# Build iPhone toolchain on iOS 5 and Mac OS X 10.7

Tags: ios, jailbreak, toolchain

Is there any good tutorials on how to build the toolchain on current iOS and OS X versions?

I can only find ones about iOS 2 and 3.

Alternatively, is it possible to compile a SBSettings Toggle without the toolchain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend you use theos for any jailbreak development, rather than the toolchain. See [this guide](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Getting_Started) to set it up.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.priyaontech.com/ndownloads/) is a link to a downloadable presentation on Beginning Jailbreak development that should provide you with an overview of the various options.